# Shopify - looping collection

Tags: shopify

I'm working with a shopify theme and I would like to loop over each product in a collection. I created a product and I added it to a collection called "landing". However, it's not appearing in this loop. Any ideas where I should look?

Thanks!

```
{% for product in collections.landing limit:3 %}
    <h3>testing</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work properly:

```
{% for product in collections.landing.products limit:3 %}
    <h3>testing</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Make sure the product you've added to the "landing" collection is set to be visible in the online store.